# Questions reguarding keeping a NuGet Package Private

Tags: nuget

Our development team is starting to run into vertical dependency issues.  I've been on teams that used Ivy to deal with this, but NuGet seems to be a far superior solution for Visual Studio 2010 / C#.

What scares me about NuGet is it makes it so easy to publish to the global feed.  If this happens accidentally, at best, I am going to get fired.  At worst . . .

I am hoping someone can vet the following plan  and tell me if I'm opening myself up to a disaster.  Also, any advice to improve the workflow would be appreciated.

1. I am under the assumption, that if I never use the "push" command, and/or I never enter an API Key, NuGet cannot publish to the public repository.  Is this true?
2. I will install a Package feed on our private intranet, where the package feed is created as described here: http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/31/hosting-simple-nuget-package-feed.aspx
3. I will alter our CruiseControl/TeamCity builds to generate a new .nupkg file on every build, and push them to the ~packages directory.
4. Team members will be forced to install the NuGet plugin, and point it towards the private repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am under the assumption, that if I never use the "push" command, and/or I never enter an API Key, NuGet cannot publish to the public repository. Is this true?

If you don't enter an API key you are 100% safe. You can type push all day long and it won't do a thing.